# htacess url rewrite rule failing when url passed as parameter

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have this URL rewrite rule

```
RewriteRule ^(send-your-request.*)$ / [NC,L,QSA,R=301]
```

it should basically just remove "/send-your-request" from the the URL (i.e. rewrite it with query string parameters from the domain i.e.

```
http://example.com/send-your-request/?a_aid=rocketnews24&pname=just%20a%20test
```

is rewritten to:

```
http://example.com/?a_aid=rocketnews24&pname=just%20a%20test
```

In that cases it works, but if I add the last parameter, it stops working

```
http://example.com/send-your-request/?a_aid=rocketnews24&pname=just%20a%20test&plink=http%3A%2F%2Fradio-eva.jp%2Fshop%2Fproducts%2Fdetail.php%3Fproduct_id%3D82
```

Can anyone tell me a better rewrite rule that can handle all the query string parameters?

**EDIT**
here are my other rules, but I have "L" on the first one, so it should stop processing right?

```
RewriteRule ^(send-your-request.*)$ / [NC,QSA,R=301,L]
Redirect 301 /products http://whiterabbitexpress.com/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)q=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1?%1s=%2 [L,R=301] 
RewriteRule ^catalogsearch/result/?$ / [NC,QSA,L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

Comment: There is no reason the additional querystring parameter shoudld cause a problem, you can test it here http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/ and it seems to rewrite just fine.

Comment: You can test it on my site here:
'http://whiterabbitexpress.com/send-your-request/?a_aid=rocketnews24&pname=just%20a%20test&plink=http%3A%2F%2Fradio-eva.jp%2Fshop%2Fproducts%2Fdetail.php%3Fproduct_id%3D82`

it works fine until the last parameter. I'm updating the post with my other rules now. but they shouldn't have any affect right?

Comment: perhaps a bug in mod_rewrite that isn't modeled in the testing tool.

Comment: doesn't work. jesus. what do I do? just wait 2 days to add a bounty? Or hire someone on odesk.com?

Comment: FWIW - I test that rule on my local apache install (v2.2) and it rewrites to the index page with the QS attached. Testing on your site, removing the "http://" from the querystring parameter causes it to work, so it might be a bug in in your version of Apache or `mod_rewrite`.

Comment: dumping the `$_REQUEST` on my index page results in: `Array
(
    [a_aid] => rocketnews24
    [pname] => just%20a%20test
    [plink] => http%3A%2F%2Fradio-eva.jp%2Fshop%2Fproducts%2Fdetail.php%3Fproduct_id%3D82
)`

Comment: could you possibly help me write a rule to strip the "http://" as well? I'm terrible with regex. but they might be a workaround. Or should I just make a new question for that?

Comment: yeah definitely something to do with the HTTP in there. Even works if I just change it from `http://` to `htp://`

Comment: could be a security feature against code injection or something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved: it was a Mod_security rule designed to protect against injection.

SecRule REQUEST_URI "=(?:ogg|gopher|data|php|zlib|(?:ht|f)tps?)://" \
          "capture,id:340165,t:none,t:urlDecodeUni,t:replaceNulls,t:compressWhiteSpace,t:lowercase,rev:275,severity:2,msg:'Atomicorp.com UNSUPPORTED DELAYED Rules: Uniencoded possible Remote File Injection attempt in URI (AE)',logdata:'%{MATCHED_VAR}'"

Was able to modify the rule via ConfigServer ModSecurity Control.

Answer (score 0):

No promises, but here is an alternative that should do the same thing, but worth a try. The `?` in the rewrite will strip the QueryString, and then the `%1` back reference will re-append it.

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (.*)
RewriteRule ^send-your-request/?$ /?%1 [NC,R=301,L]
```

It's worth noting that the QueryString is automatically pass with the rewrite and the `QSA` modifier just appends a additional parameters if a `?` is present in your rewrite - if you omit `QSA` and include `?` in the rewrite, it will strip the existing QueryString. You might also try leaving off `QSA`.

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^send-your-request/?$ / [NC,R=301,L]
```

Comment: thanks, but, no good. same result: works without the final param, but not with it... going to try posting to ServerFault... thank you for the attempt!